# Java Serializable - Does serializing/deserializing have security?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a question that is based off of the Serializable class.

Sadly after searching on Google, I could not find any answers that satisfy my question.

Here is what I am doing:

Sending a serialized object via UDP (DatagramPacket) to a server.

The Packet class is an abstract class that all Packets should be inheriting.
Packet is Serializable and it has a generated UUID as a static variable.
Both the client and the server have this generated UUID.

The server deserializes the object, checks if it inherits Packet, and then evaluates what Packet class (server-sided) it properly needs to be casted to.

I want to know if serializing and casting an object is secure in a way; with this being said:

If someone modified the client side packet class and added new methods and fields and so forth, would the casting of that object to the server-side object still be eligible?

Hopefully this can be cleared up nicely.

Comment: This link might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vQf4qyMXg#t=3366

Comment: I don't understand what you think modifying a class to add methods and fields has to do with security.

Comment: ....did you even read my post?

I'm sending a serialized object from a client to a server representing a game packet.

Someone modifies the object client-sided and tries sending it. I'm asking how Serializable pertains to this general area, hence why I said security.

I don't think you understand anything about this topic at all.

Comment: *Did you even read my post? ... I don't think you understand anything about this topic at all.* Sparta, I'm fairly certain that EJP knows an order of magnitude more about serialization than you do. Or perhaps several. I would have given you the benefit of the doubt until I read your comment. Your question is quite confused and would certainly benefit from clarification. Good luck getting an answer with an attitude like that.

Comment: Already got an answer. If you can't comprehend such a simple question that I don't know what you can comprehend. Parth Satra, a fairly new member, understood it well enough to answer. I don't appreciate downgrading comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are security implications of the serializable objects as they expose the private variables.
Reference : [Serializable Interface](http://webmoli.com/2008/01/27/what-is-the-magic-serializable-interface-does-in-java/)

With respect to adding new fields and methods, there are certain things that are compatible and some that aren't. Please check this post for more details.
[Java Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124664/java-serialization-uid-not-changed-can-i-add-new-variables-and-method-to-the-c)

Also for more details check : [IBM Dev Works : Java Things](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things1/)

I hope this is what you were looking for.