# Is Serialization independent of methods?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have two classes, one on the server and one on the client app which have the same fields and Constructors but different methods. (*specifically the server class has setters while client side has not*)

I have read on Oracle docs that `Serializable` interface allows me to preserve the state of an object and from what I understand it packs the fields during serialization and rebuilds the object on deserialization.

What is not clear to me is whether I need to have an exact copy of the class or are those methods unimportant for serialization and I can use 2 different classes with same fields and Constructors.

Comment: Interesting. I've never thought of such design. I usually just use the same beans packed in the same jar both on the client and the server to avoid code duplication, and dont bother myself about the object being mutable on the client side

Comment: Well, it certainly would be easier to have the same robust class on both ends but I may want some methods on the client side and different ones on the server side and just wondered if it was possible. Maybe a different design would solve this problem as well?

Comment: If you have left SerialVersionUID to be created by runtime then yes it will use your method names. If you save an instance of Object and then try to desearlize it but this time your class has different method names it wont work.

Comment: I have set `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;`

Comment: @AndrewRegan just take a sample class, have a simple field say name. create the getter/setter. Ensure you dont have SerialVersionUID set, then serialize an instance of your class. Go back and edit/modify say getter method name from getName to getThisName. Try to deserialize your previously serialized object.

Comment: "If the SUID is not declared for a class, the value defaults to the hash for that class." taken from [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html) so yes, not defining SUID will make it dependent on how the class is structured for the hash to fit, but with custom SUID this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - according to the list of [Type Changes Affecting Serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#a6678) (Java 8), which has a list of compatible and incompatible changes, the only methods that have any bearing on compatibility are:

- `writeObject` and `readObject`
- `writeReplace` and `readResolve`

So changing getters and setters should have no impact. It's really only once you start changing fields that you get into problems.

See also: [Java serialization, UID not changed. Can I add new variables and method to the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124664/java-serialization-uid-not-changed-can-i-add-new-variables-and-method-to-the-c)

**Update:** this does, of course, assume that both instances of the class have the same, explicitly set, value of `serialVersionUID`, which is true for this question. The above rules determine whether a change to the class spec on one side is *compatible with* - or else breaks - the contract that the UID implies. If `serialVersionUID` is **not** set on either side, and given that the [UID-generation rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#a4100) are much more comprehensive (i.e. method names, modifiers, signatures **are** included) then almost any change to either class will be deemed incompatible.

**Update 2:** I'd need a Java class rewriter to produce a fully standalone test case to confirm that the Java 8 document I cited is correct, and that serialization is *remarkably tolerant and resilient* provided `serialVersionUID`has been used correctly. However, I've observed that adding/removing methods has no effect, and that adding/removing fields is generally handled very tolerantly. The only incompatibility I was able to cause was by changing the **type** of a field between class versions.

Comment: I read the question you referenced to, yet it still discusses only the option of adding new fields and methods on both sides if I am correct. I still don't know whether having class A with methods A and B is compatible with class B with methods X and Y, while both having the same field and constructor. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: I tried to answer that directly, so I will edit to clarify later, but the short answer is Yes, you can change methods (apart from the 4 I mentioned) in the case where the UIDs match.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, you use the serialization to write and read data with the same class.  If your fields are identical (names, types, order), it might work with different classes.  Nice idea!

You could consider the use of XStreams.  This library serialises via reflection and is less restrictive than the normal serialization.

Comment: It will definitely *not* work with different classes. You will get a `ClassCastException`.it would work with different implementations of the *same* class subject to the explicit `serialVersionUID` stipulation.

Comment: @EJP I think you misunterstood me.  And this is my fault.  Sorry.  There were a "server" and a "client" in the question.  So I thought that there were two seperate JVMs.  With "different classes" I meant different classes with the same name.  If the serialVersionUID is appropiate, the "reading JVM" might be able to interpret the stream.  I admit that "different classes" is not an optimal description for this.  Hint for me:  Always refresh the browser before submitting an answer or a comment :(