# Java: Local caching and changes

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a class with name and age

```
class Person implements serializable {
   int age;
   String name;
}
```

I have an ArrayList of this class

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>
```

When tomcat shuts down, I save the above to a local file:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(persons);
        out.flush();
        byte[] objBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        File file = new File("./persons.bin");
        Files.write(objBytes, file);      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
```

and when tomcat starts up, I load the file back:

```
        File file = new File("./persons.bin");
        if (!file.exists()) return;
        byte[] objBytes = Files.toByteArray(file);

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(objBytes);
        ObjectInput in = null;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            ArrayList<Person> persons = (ArrayList<Person>) in.readObject();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
```

The above works as expected. My question is what will happen if later on the Person class will be added with new properties, for example:

```
class Person implements serializable {
   int age;
   String name;
   String address;
}
```

I'm not using Gson because of the overhead it creates and I prefer to save the data as binary. Will the above fail? Succeed but address will be null? Weird things will happen? Do I have any control over what can be done in such cases?

Thanks

**Edit**: For the class I have

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java serialization, UID not changed. Can I add new variables and method to the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124664/java-serialization-uid-not-changed-can-i-add-new-variables-and-method-to-the-c)

Comment: Check the second answer provided in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4125086/415749

Comment: Yeah, I was reading exactly that and it means that if I'll keep serialVersionUID as 1L, everything will be intact (new props will get null,0,"" etc...) The question is, whether this answer is "correct", it was never marked as such.

Comment: You can test both the scenarios quickly with your example.

Answer (score 1):

It will break! You have to define a serialVersionUID or otherwise one will be created based on the properties of the class. So if you change the class the serialVersionUID would change aswell. If the UID don't match InvalidClassException is thrown.

Saving objects instead of the state of the object comes with alot of problems through and I recommend to save them in a more appropriate format. JSON, XML or even CSVs... Seriously that bit of overhead will save you from alot of trouble later on.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, please see the edited post. So despite private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; If I'll add new props and keep serialVersionUID as 1 or change it to 2L, my class would break?

Comment: If you leave the serialVersionUID at 1L and add properties they will be ignored and stay at their default value. (null for objects etc.). You can define how your object should be serialized/desiralized by providing a readObject and writeObject method in your Person class.

Comment: That's what I read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4125086/415749 so it won't break if I'll keep the same serialVersionUID . You wrote "So if you change the class the serialVersionUID would change aswell" - this is incorrect. As I wrote in my post's comment, the linked answer was never marked as "correct" so I wonder if it is.

Comment: The official documentation says that if not present a default serialVersionUID will be generated based on the fields in the class. So if you add let's say a "int age" InvalidClassException is thrown. Of course if you've got your own serialVersionUID it (probably) won't break, because fields are no longer taken into account. I think my sentence is just a bit misleading. If you defined a serialVersionUID don't change it.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant with this sentence :)